# Dry query, adding a where clause inside an if statement later on in php

Tags: php, jquery, where-clause, dry

I'm a fan of a dry code. I'm not sure is doable but I'm trying to save me from writing a double query.

Here's my example:

```
$link       = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$link_array = explode('/', $link);
$page       = end($link_array);
```

In the first part of my code, I'm parsing my link.

```
if (strpos($link, 'something') !== false) {

    $sql = $ee->db->query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE order_id = '$page'");
        foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {
            $tracking_code = $row->tracking_id;
            $carrier_name  = $row->carrier_name;
            echo "The real carrier name is: {$carrier_name} .<br>";
            echo "The real tracking code is: " . $tracking_code . ' .<br>';
} else {

    $sql = $ee->db->query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE order_hash = '$page'");
        foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {
            $tracking_code = $row->tracking_id;
            $carrier_name  = $row->carrier_name;
            echo "The real carrier name is: {$carrier_name} .<br>";
            echo "The real tracking code is: " . $tracking_code . ' .<br>';
}
```

Then I run two queries: depends on the link that I'm parsing I'm gonna retrieve two different set of data.

I was wondering if it is possible to have a different approach, something in this line:

```
$sql = $ee->db->query("SELECT * FROM `mytable`");
```

right after my variables and then, inside the if statement:

```
if (strpos($link, 'something') !== false) {
    $sql =. $ee->db->query("WHERE order_id = '$page'");
    #code
} else {
    $sql =. $ee->db->query("WHERE order_hash = '$page'");
    #code
}
```

Or any other way to avoid to rewrite my code could be fine. In this case I'm not gonna save a lot, I'm just trying to understand what it could be the best approach.

Comment: You're going to be given a hard time here if you don't use $db->prepare. This is wide open to SQL injection

Comment: I'm working with espressionengine and codeignition, the $ee->db->query is a prepared statement

Comment: If you like dry code, you should probably look into some PHP frameworks. It's a piece of cake for a majority of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlooking the injected `$page` variable issue, you really only need to replace the column name it looks like:

```
$sql = $ee->db->query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE order_".((strpos($link, 'something') !== false)? "id" : "hash")." = '$page'");

foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {
    $tracking_code = $row->tracking_id;
    $carrier_name  = $row->carrier_name;
    echo "The real carrier name is: {$carrier_name} .<br>";
    echo "The real tracking code is: " . $tracking_code . ' .<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just modify the beginning:

Use a ternary operator here (basically a one liner if statement)

```
$sql = ( (strpos($link,'something') !== false) ? $ee->db->query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE order_id = '$page'") : $ee->db->query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE order_hash = '$page'") );
```

If you don't like that style, you could do this:

```
$sql = $ee->db->query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE ");

if( strpos($link,'something') !== false ) { 
    $sql .= "order_id   = '$page'"
}else{
}   $sql .= "order_hash = '$page'";
```

Then once $sql is set, you can now run that foreach once, since it's the same code either way

```
 foreach ($sql->result() as $row) {
            $tracking_code = $row->tracking_id;
            $carrier_name  = $row->carrier_name;
            echo "The real carrier name is: {$carrier_name} .<br>";
            echo "The real tracking code is: " . $tracking_code . ' .<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using DRY for queries (especially simple queries like the on in your example) usually is not a good idea. It creates a mess and makes your code less readable and harder to maintain. I would not recommend it, but if you really want to do it, just use a string variable for the SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `mytable`";
if (strpos($link, 'something') !== false) {
    $sql =. "WHERE order_id = '$page'";
} else {
    $sql =. "WHERE order_hash = '$page'";
}
$query = $ee->db->query($sql);
```

Also make sure to use prepare statements to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Don't forget space before `WHERE`. It's not strictly needed here because the backtick is a token delimiter, but in many other cases it's needed and it's good practice to create a more readable SQL string.